# comparing files by fields in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, uniq

I have two arbitrary files:

```
==> file1 <==
11110 abcdef
11111 apple
11112 banana
11113 carrot
11114 date
11115 eggplant

==> file2 <==
11110 abcdefg
11111 apple-pie
11112 banana-cake
11113 chocolate
11115 egg
11116 fruit
```

For the sake of comparison of these files, I only care about the number in the first column, the words after the break are unimportant.

**I want to be able to readily identify numbers that are missing from each file.**

For example, file 1 has no `11116` and file 2 has no `11114`.

If I sort the files together I can get a complete list:

```
$ sort file*
11110 abcdef
11110 abcdefg
11111 apple
11111 apple-pie
11112 banana
11112 banana-cake
11113 carrot
11113 chocolate
11114 date
11115 egg
11115 eggplant
11116 fruit
```

I can get a list of all the numbers by running it through uniq and only comparing the length of the number:

```
$ sort file* | uniq -w5
11110 abcdef
11111 apple
11112 banana
11113 carrot
11114 date
11115 egg
11116 fruit
```

That's a list of all numbers 11110-11116.

I can get a list of uniques and duplicates by asking uniq to filter those for me:

duplicates (numbers that appear in both files):

```
$ sort file* | uniq -dw5
11110 abcdef
11111 apple
11112 banana
11113 carrot
11115 egg
```

unique numbers, or numbers that only appear in one file:

```
$ sort file* | uniq -uw5
11114 date
11116 fruit
```

I would like something that has output resembling:

```
# shows numbers that do not exist in this file
$ sort file* | <is missing>
==> file1 <==
11116 fruit

==> file2 <==
11114 date
```

It could do the reverse and show what numbers are missing from the OTHER file, each case is workable:

```
# shows numbers that do exist ONLY in this file
$ sort file* | <has unqie>
==> file1 <==
11114 date

==> file2 <==
11116 fruit
```

The first field will contain ~30 alphanumeric characters.

The files in question contain thousands of entries and the majority of entries are expected to be in both files.

The arbitrary data to the right of the number is relevant and needs to remain.

I had the idea of:

- generate a complete list of numbers
- compare that list with file1 searching for unique entries
- compare that list with file2 searching for unique entries

But I can't work out how to do that on a single line:

```
sort file* | uniq -w5 | sort file1 | uniq -uw5
sort file* | uniq -w5 | sort file2 | uniq -uw5
```

However, the output of the first uniq doesn't get merged in with the resorting of file1/2...

The solution I came up with was to create the output of all the numbers:

```
$ sort file* | uniq -w5
```

and then run that against each file individually, that does work. I just couldn't piece it together on one line:

```
$ sort all file1 | uniq -uw5
11116 fruit
$ sort all file2 | uniq -uw5
11114 date
```

I am now working on incorporating join, thanks Kamil

---

edit: I never got to go any further myself, @Shawn gave it to me in one very short line:

```
join -j1 -v1 file1 file2
```

After I have two compiled lists in the format I require, a `join` performed on the files spits out the required answer. From my code examples above:

```
$join -j1 -v1 file1 file2
11114 date

$ join -j1 -v2 file1 file2
11116 fruit
```

## A real world Example:

I thought I would generate a real world example of what I have been working on. Take 5 arbitrary files:

```
 lorem1.txt
 lorem2.txt
 lorem3.txt
 lorem4.txt
 lorem5.txt
```

and make a backup of them. I have modified one bit in `lorem2.txt` and I removed `lorem4.txt from the backup (consider it a new file, or for whatever reason, it is just a missing file):

```
test$ tree
.
├── data
│   ├── lorem1.txt
│   ├── lorem2.txt
│   ├── lorem3.txt
│   ├── lorem4.txt
│   └── lorem5.txt
└── data-backup
    ├── lorem1.txt
    ├── lorem2.txt
    ├── lorem3.txt
    └── lorem5.txt

2 directories, 9 files
mad@test$ md5deep data/* | sort > hash1
mad@test$ md5deep data-backup/* | sort > hash2
mad@test$ head hash*
==> hash1 <==
44da5caec444b6f00721f499e97c857a  /test/data/lorem1.txt
5ba24c9a5f6d74f81499872877a5061d  /test/data/lorem2.txt
a00edd450c533091e0f62a06902545a4  /test/data/lorem5.txt
b80118923d16f649dd5410d54e5acb2d  /test/data/lorem4.txt
fb8f7f39344394c78ab02d2ac524df9d  /test/data/lorem3.txt

==> hash2 <==
000e755b8e840e42d50ef1ba5c7ae45d  /test/data-backup/lorem2.txt
44da5caec444b6f00721f499e97c857a  /test/data-backup/lorem1.txt
a00edd450c533091e0f62a06902545a4  /test/data-backup/lorem5.txt
fb8f7f39344394c78ab02d2ac524df9d  /test/data-backup/lorem3.txt
```

Running our `join`s:

**join 1**

```
mad@test$ join -j1 -v1 hash*
5ba24c9a5f6d74f81499872877a5061d /test/data/lorem2.txt
b80118923d16f649dd5410d54e5acb2d /test/data/lorem4.txt
```

From our two sets of hash files, `join`ing them verified against the first file, we see that the matching hashes of `lorem2.txt` and lorem4.txt`are missing from the second file. (`lorem2`because we changed a bit, and`lorem4` because we didn't copy, or we deleted the file from the backup).

Doing the reverse join we can see `lorem2` exists, it's just that the hash is incorrect:

**join 2**

```
mad@test$ join -j1 -v2 hash*
000e755b8e840e42d50ef1ba5c7ae45d /test/data-backup/lorem2.txt
```

Using my `sort` and `uniq` examples from earlier, I could get similar results, but the `join` above is much better. **join1** shows us files we need to revisit, **join2** specifically shows us what hashes are incorrect.

**sort by name and show uniq names** (which was way outside the scope of the original question) can show us files that are missing from the backup. In this example, I convert the backup filenames so they mimic the original filenames, merge/sort them with the original filenames and sort based only on the names, not the hashes. This will show files that are missing from the backup:

```
test$ sort -k2 hash1 <(sed 's/data-backup/data/g' hash2) | uniq -uf1
b80118923d16f649dd5410d54e5acb2d  /test/data/lorem4.txt
```

if we had a file that contained all the hashes:

```
test$ sort -k2 hash1 allhashes | uniq -uf1
b80118923d16f649dd5410d54e5acb2d  /test/data/lorem4.txt
```

Thanks again to everyone who helped me formulate this. It has turned into a real life and time saver.

Comment: We have a cubic kilometer of near-duplicates. Can you show us what you have already searched for and what you found? A trivial Awk script should not be hard to find, for example.

Comment: I was attempting to demonstrate that I have been working through it. I did come up with **an** answer but I can't work it into one line.

Comment: [man join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join). Join on the first field and print unpariable lines from both files.

Comment: @KamilCuk excellent, thanks, I didn't know about join!

Comment: In particular, assuming the files are sorted, `join -j1 -v1 file1 file2` will print records that are only in file1, and `join -j1 -v2 file1 file2` records only in file2.

Comment: I would like to encourage @KamilCuk and @Shawn to submit an answer with join. I I DO like the `awk` answer however, I have always found `awk` quite difficult and never got it as a whole. I was able to solve it with `sort` and `uniq` but the `join` answer was the most easily constructed one that answers it in few clear steps. Notably, what shawn put together just works a treat. Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk`, you can make use of this approach:

```
awk 'ARGIND < ARGC-1 {
   a[ARGIND][$1] = 1
   next
} {
for (i=1; i<ARGC-1; i++)
   if (!a[i][$1])
      print ARGV[i] ":", $0
}' file1 file2 <(sort file1 file2)
```

```
file2: 11114 date
file1: 11116 fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

Only in file1:

```
grep `comm -23 <(cut -d \  -f 1 f1 | sort) <(cut -d \  -f 1 f2 | sort)` f1
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk version only takes one pass through each file:
It assumes that there are no duplicate IDs in a file.

```
awk '
    NR == FNR   {f1[$1] = $0; next}
    !($1 in f1) {printf "only in %s: %s\n", FILENAME, $0}
      $1 in f1  {delete f1[$1]}
    END         {for (id in f1) printf "only in %s: %s\n", ARGV[1], f1[id]}
' file1 file2
```

ouputs

```
only in file2: 11116 fruit
only in file1: 11114 date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff between 2 files.  However, if you diff these files all the lines will listed.

```
$ diff file1 file2
1,6c1,6
< 11110 abcdef
< 11111 apple
< 11112 banana
< 11113 carrot
< 11114 date
< 11115 eggplant
---
> 11110 abcdefg
> 11111 apple-pie
> 11112 banana-cake
> 11113 chocolate
> 11115 egg
> 11116 fruit
```

But you only care about the leading numbers.

```
$ diff <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1) <(cut -d' ' -f1 file2)
5d4
< 11114
6a6
> 11116
```

If the files are not sorted then add a sort

```
$ diff <(cut -d' ' -f1 file1 | sort) <(cut -d' ' -f1 file2 | sort)
5d4
< 11114
6a6
> 11116
```